# How to have minimap for mobile artillery like on the PC?

Tags: battlefield-3

Do they press M for it, or is it automatic? If it's automatic then how do you do it on consoles?

Comment: What is this even about? What weapon or what vehicle? Sometimes games don't get the same features on every system also, just so you know.

Comment: I thought that the minimap was PC only and you had to use the pause menu if you're playing on console.

Answer (score 1):

It is automatic. If you don't get it, you are probably playing on a hardcore server. Try playing on normal(softcore)